# C++ - How to pass a comparator to STL functions correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I wrote a `PointCollection` class.

`PointCollection` holds a bunch of points.

It has 2 member functions.

`addPoint(Point point)`

`findNearestKPoints(Point center, int k)`

Each time the `findNearestKPoints` is called, a `center` is specified to find k nearest points around it.

But it can't compile:

`error: called object type 'bool (PointCollection::*)(const Point &, const Point &) const' is not a function or function pointer`

How to do it correctly?

My code is bellow as a reference:

```
struct Point {
    int val_;
    Point() {}
    Point(int val) : val_(val) {}
};

class PointCollection {
private:
    vector<Point> points_;
    Point center_;
public:
    PointCollection() {}
    virtual ~PointCollection() {}

    void addPoint(const Point &point) {
        points_.push_back(point);
    }

    bool compare(const Point &a, const Point &b) const {
        return std::abs(a.val_ - center_.val_) < std::abs(b.val_ - center_.val_);
    }

    vector<Point> findNearestKPoints(Point center, int k) {
        center_ = center;

        nth_element(points_.begin(), points_.begin() + k - 1, points_.end(), 
                    &PointCollection::compare);

        return vector<Point>(points_.begin(), points_.begin() + k);
    }
};
```

Comment: Your `compare` function as written requires an instance on which to work, which from looking at the contents of that function are unnecessary.  Make it `static`, or make it a non-member `friend` function.

Comment: @Chad: The function uses the member `center_`, so it is necessary.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ugh --- yeah.  And that makes me think it is just _wrong_.  A binary compare function almost always compares the passed in objects, and doesn't attempt a tertiary compare...  I don't know enough about this particular problem domain to say if it's wrong or not though.

Comment: @Chad the PointCollection holds a bunch of points. Each time the findNearestKPoints is called, a center is specified to find k nearest points around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A comparator is a callable object. In other words: a function pointer or a lambda closure, or a class with a suitable `operator()`.

`&PointCollection::compare` is not a callable object. It's a class method. It is not a callable object for the simple reason that you cannot call it directly. A class method can only be called on *an instance of the class*. You must have an instance of this class somewhere, and you call its `compare()` method. It looks like a function, but it really isn't. It's a class method.

One easy solution would be to capture `this` via a lambda, something like (C++14):

```
nth_element(points_.begin(), points_.begin() + k - 1, points_.end(),
              [this](const auto &a, const auto &b)
                  {
                      return this->compare(a, b);
                  });
```

The lambda captures `this`, and `compare()` can be invoked on `this`, just like it can be called directly from the parent method.

P.S. your `findNearestKPoints()` is returning a `vector<Point>`, and not `vector<int>`, as you declared it.

Comment: in case of C++14 not being an option, std::bind from C++11 could be of help too(just a note if someone stumbles apon this and is unwilling/unable to use C++14)

Comment: Those people could also just change `auto` to the concrete type (`Point` in this case).

Comment: Actually, the *only* reason to need to capture `this` is to access `this->center_` ... which is just a copy of the argument `center` passed to the function.  It would be better to make `compare` be a static function of three arguments, and make the lambda capture `center` directly.  (Or write out the `compare` function in the lambda.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks. According to your idea. I answer my question below.

Comment: @ShihaoXu: However the critical part of this answer is the second paragraph, explaining why your original code didn't work.  The example solution code is just a minor detail.

Answer (score 2):

The functor solution is elegant as well, to complete the picture.

You can add this functor inside (or outside) the PointCollection class:

```
struct compare {
    Point center_;
    bool operator()(const Point &a, const Point &b) const {
        return std::abs(a.val_ - center_.val_) < std::abs(b.val_ - center_.val_);
    }
 }
```

Then:

```
std::nth_element(points_.begin(), points_.begin() + k - 1, points_.end(), compare{center} );
```

Advantage over lambda: easier and more convenient to instantiate the comparator (functor)  wherever you want to use it, while the lambda needs to be written all over again (imagine you need also to write other methods that need to use the comparator, i.e. farthestK, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

center is a temporary variable, not necessary to store it as a member variable.

Final version:

```
class PointCollection {
private:
    vector<Point> points_;
public:
    PointCollection(vector<int> nums) {
        for (int num : nums) {
            points_.push_back({num});
        }
    }
    virtual ~PointCollection() {}

    void addPoint(const Point &point) {
        points_.push_back(point);
    }

    vector<Point> findNearestKPoints(Point center, int k) {
        nth_element(points_.begin(), points_.begin() + k - 1, points_.end(),
                    [&center] (const Point &a, const Point &b) {
                        return compare(a, b, center);
                    });

        return vector<Point>(points_.begin(), points_.begin() + k);
    }

    static bool compare(const Point &a, const Point &b, Point center) {
        return std::abs(a.val_ - center.val_) < std::abs(b.val_ - center.val_);
    }
};
```

Comment: This will work as well. Although, this approach becomes slightly inefficient when the captured object is large. Because it's captured by value, it will have to be copy-constructed. If that were the case, just capture it by reference.